# RPI - Configuring ethernet

Tags: ethernet, raspberry-pi

I need to connect to my university network which is a bit tricky doing on RPI. 
I cannot find how to complete the manual set up steps described on   [uni site](https://footprints.york.ac.uk/MRcgi/MRTicketPage.pl?USER=&MRP=0&MAJOR_MODE=DETAILS&MAXMININC=&MRNUMBERLIST=&LASTID=30723&ABN=&GRPDETAIL=&HISTORYKEY=&CUSTM=&MR=32624&PROJECTID=1) , and the app that configures network automatically isnt working. 
The script looks for CPU architecture and compares it with the following: x86(i386,i686,i486,i586) and x86_64. Although in rpi case it returns error as processor type is arw61.

If you know a way to follow the steps described on manual set-up, or how i should execute the script, please let me know.

Atm I am using raspbian-wheezy although I dont mind switching if that gets me online.

Following is the settings script:

```
#!/bin/sh

download_x86()
{
    wget --output-document="/tmp/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2" http://autoconnect.york.ac.uk//tools/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2
}

download_x64()
{
    wget --output-document="/tmp/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2" http://autoconnect.york.ac.uk//tools/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2
}

export HW_TYPE=`uname -m`

if [ "$HW_TYPE" = "i686" ] || [ "$HW_TYPE" = "i386" ] || [ "$HW_TYPE" = "i486" ] || [ "$HW_TYPE" = "i586" ]
then
    if [ -f "cabs/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2" ]
    then
    echo "Running x86 version..."
    export MY_DIR="`pwd`"
    cd /tmp
    tar xvjf "$MY_DIR/cabs/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2"
    "./XpressConnect-x86"
    else
      if [ -f "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2" ]
      then
      echo "Running x86 version from /tmp..."
      cd /tmp
      tar xvjf "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2"
          rm -f "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2"
      "./XpressConnect-x86"
      else
      echo "Will download x86 version..."
      download_x86
      if [ "0" = "$?" ]
      then
              cd /tmp
          tar xvjf "XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2"
          "./XpressConnect-x86"
      else
          echo "Unable to download the x86 version.   Please check your network connection" > /tmp/ubrun
          echo "and verify it is working properly!" >> /tmp/ubrun
          echo "(URL : http://autoconnect.york.ac.uk//tools/XpressConnect-x86.tar.bz2)" >> /tmp/ubrun
          echo "" >> /tmp/ubrun
          uname -a >> /tmp/ubrun
          xmessage -file /tmp/ubrun
          rm /tmp/ubrun
      fi
      fi
    fi
else 
     if [ "$HW_TYPE" = "x86_64" ]
     then
     if [ -f "cabs/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2" ]
     then
         echo "Running x64 version..."
         export MY_DIR="`pwd`"
         cd /tmp
         tar xvjf "$MY_DIR/cabs/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2"
         "./XpressConnect-x64"
       else
       if [ -f "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2" ]
       then
           echo "Running x64 version from /tmp..."
           cd /tmp
           tar xvjf "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2"
               rm -f "/tmp/cabs/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2"
           "./XpressConnect-x64"
       else
           echo "Will download x64 version..."
           download_x64

           if [ "0" = "$?" ];
           then
           cd /tmp
           tar xvjf "XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2"
           "/tmp/XpressConnect-x64"
           else
           echo "Unable to download the x64 version.   Please check your network connection" > /tmp/ubrun
           echo "and verify it is working properly!" >> /tmp/ubrun
           echo "(URL : http://autoconnect.york.ac.uk//tools/XpressConnect-x64.tar.bz2)" >> /tmp/ubrun
           echo "" >> /tmp/ubrun
           uname -a >> /tmp/ubrun
           xmessage -file /tmp/ubrun
           rm /tmp/ubrun
           fi
           fi
     fi
     else
    echo "Unable to determine the type of processor in this machine.  Reported type was " $HW_TYPE "."
    xmessage "Unable to determine the type of processor in this machine. Reported type was " $HW_TYPE "."
     fi
fi
```

etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa- roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

etc/resolv.conf:

```
domain sns.york.ac.uk
search sns.york.ac.uk
nameserver 144.32.128.110
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0 Link ecap: Ethernet HWaddr b8:27:eb:f4:66:77
inet addr:172.17.63.53 bcase: 172.11.62.255 Mask 225.225.224.0
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 METRIC:1
PX PACKETS: 702 ERROS:0 DROPPED 0 OVERRUNNS0 FRAME 0
TX packets 303 errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0
collisions 0 txquelen:100
RX bytes 152123 TX bytes 341232
```

Comment: More details please. Are you using wi-fi or ethernet? If wi-fi, what kind of adapter are you using? See the link for a script that can help with wi-fi setups... http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=6256. I can assist, but I need more detail.

Comment: I am using ethernet.

Comment: Is there anything similar to the network manager described on university page?

Comment: Well, that simplifies everything a whole bunch. Can you please post the following file contents: /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/resolv.conf, and also post the output from ifconfig and netstat -r.

Comment: Ok bare with me cause i need to type everything in.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on the command line, or through a terminal? Are you using LXDE at all? If so, you should start from this link: http://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCMan's_Complete_LXDE_Setup_Guide. You should be able to follow your Uni's instructions and use the GUI as detailed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6590/discussion-between-giannis-and-ian-atkin)